# is it necessary to to fill bank detail in apple account for testing in-app purchase?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

i am cerating in app purchase for my app.but it gives the response.products blank in productsRequest:didReceiveResponse:. further the product id is shown as invalid.
i have gone through [this](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/).

the only step i didn't do is filling bank details on apple account, so my question is does it is compulsory to fill bank details for testing in app purchase.

i have also gone through stack overflow for same question but can't find proper solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have to have a valid paid contract with all part filled to test In App Purchase. I had the same issue and didn't receive any product before the bank details were completed.

Comment: can you please help on following. in my app i am providing in app purchase for 1 week, 2 week ,1 month and 3 month, if user buy 1 week subscription then how to remove that but after 1 week.how do i make user to buy that again once its period is expired.

Comment: I have never used subscription or renewable in-app, but you may find help here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-SW6

Comment: you gonna give deposit or no ?